# Proxy Server on top of Several Node Machines to route the requests

Tags: node.js, nginx, proxy, reverse-proxy

I have several machines with node.js installed on them and I want to have a proxy server on top of all of them which will handle and route the requests.

Please look at the diagram

[image]

the number of machines is dynamic and will keep changing and therefore I want a flexible system to be tied with it - config file.

I am planning to have a reverse proxy server which will work based on inputs taken from a config file. The requests will have some specific string which can be matched with data already in config file and then based on results the proxy server will forward the request to specific machine.

For Example - Let's say I have 5 node machines and in config file I have an object where from A-E the ip of machines are saved. Now the request will have an alphabet from A-E and based on that the request will get routed to specific node machine.

My Questions?

Can nginx work for this? If yes, please point me to right direction because I haven't been able to get my hands on a dynamic config based environment for it.

If no - suggest something.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, you're looking for load balancing, something nginx is most definitely capable of.

Comment: @gelliott181 from what I have read till now, in nginx I'll have to hardcode everything as in the ips and stuff and it'll be linked to the url directly. I want to make the whole process dynamic and therefore if any changes I make in the separate config file it'll automatically work the next time any request come in.

Comment: Yes, there's some config to be done, but no it's definitely not a requirement to hard code everything. At some point, yes, you must hard code the IPs and things, but those can be done in a variable which allows nginx to handle load balancing based on your selected algorithm. Check out https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/understanding-nginx-http-proxying-load-balancing-buffering-and-caching. It's dense, but it covers load balancing and nginx will automatically reroute traffic away from down hosts as you mentioned (nodes may be added or removed at any time).

Comment: I'll read it and then update you on this. @gelliott181

Comment: I hope it helps you out, even if all it does is give you a new way to word your question so someone with more nginx time can get your config going.